# Connection refused when running my vertx3 http handler in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, vert.x

I'm trying to deploy a vertx3 service on docker swarm but when I run

```
$ curl localhost:4000
   curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused
```

and I can't figure out how to make it work, help appreciated. See below the code and more info.

This is my vertx3 application

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(r -> {
        r.response().end("<h1>Powered by Vert.x3</h1>");
    }).listen(8080, result -> {
      if (result.succeeded()) {
          fut.complete();
      } else {
            fut.fail(result.cause());
          }
      });
  }
}
```

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM vertx/vertx3
ENV VERTICLE_NAME com.shop.services.products.MainVerticle
ENV VERTICLE_FILE target/products-3.5.1.jar
ENV VERTICLE_HOME /usr/verticles
EXPOSE 8080
COPY $VERTICLE_FILE $VERTICLE_HOME/
WORKDIR $VERTICLE_HOME
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["exec vertx run $VERTICLE_NAME -cp $VERTICLE_HOME/*"]
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: sergionava89/products:v1
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

I try to run a local docker swarm

```
docker swarm init
```

then I get this message

```
Error response from daemon: could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on interface enp0s25 (2a02:c7d:501a:f200:84fc:532e:737a:7a21 and 2a02:c7d:501a:f200:ad08:5748:44d4:6726) - specify one with --advertise-addr
```

so I run the following

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 2a02:c7d:501a:f200:84fc:532e:737a:7a21
```

then launch the container

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml shop
```

to which I get

```
Creating network shop_webnet
Creating service shop_web
```

when I try to hit the endpoint I get

```
$ curl localhost:4000
   curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused
```

Output of docker service

```
docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                      PORTS
sj8k1hd26cbk        shop_web            replicated          5/5                 sergionava89/products:v1   *:4000->8080/tcp

docker service ps shop_web
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                      NODE                    DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE           ERROR               PORTS
sjsoh7atv24x        shop_web.1          sergionava89/products:v1   sergio-ThinkPad-T431s   Running             Running 9 minutes ago                       
owakk9xqty69        shop_web.2          sergionava89/products:v1   sergio-ThinkPad-T431s   Running             Running 9 minutes ago                       
yvlopiq6vtjh        shop_web.3          sergionava89/products:v1   sergio-ThinkPad-T431s   Running             Running 9 minutes ago                       
op7yv8vuliuk        shop_web.4          sergionava89/products:v1   sergio-ThinkPad-T431s   Running             Running 9 minutes ago                       
z8imj3b572tg        shop_web.5          sergionava89/products:v1   sergio-ThinkPad-T431s   Running             Running 9 minutes ago
```

Comment: try `curl 127.0.0.1:4000`

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. @ConstantinGalbenu Could you help me understand the reason why?

Comment: `If localhost doesn't work but 127.0.0.1 does, then it's likely wget attempts to connect over IPv6 instead of IPv4. Try wget -4 localhost:8080` https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26817#issuecomment-330272420

Comment: yes that's it, curl -4 localhost:4000 works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments 127.0.0.1:4000 works